# 'de' in Yo me alegro de no estudiar

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

Yo me alegro de no estudiar: la mejor escuela es el teatro. 
(Literally?!:) *I am glad to not study: the best school is the theater.*

Why is *de* used in this example? Is *que (that)* a reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepositions in both languages are not equal, it is a nightmare for Spanish people to learn English prepositions, and viceversa can happen the same ;)

`To` can be translated as `a, de, hacia, ...`

`De` can be translated to `from, of, to, by, ...`

If I give you the case

> Which are the effects of not studying ?

The literal translation would be

> Cuales son los efectos de no estudiar ?

As you see estudiar on his infinitive form is preceded by de and in English, gerund is preceded by of.

A trick is mentioned [http://spanish.about.com/](http://spanish.about.com/cs/verbs/a/infinitive_prep.htm)

> One of the most common uses of infinitives is as the object of a preposition. When used in such a way, **the infinitive is often the rough equivalent of the English gerund, that is, the "-ing" form of the verb, and can be translated in that way**.

`Que` would not be correct ¿*Me alegro que no estudiar*?. If you put an example it would be better. 
`Que` is used as `that/who/which` when you use it as relative pronoun.

The person who/that found me was very kind --> La persona que me encontró era muy amable.

The students that study will pass the exam --> Los estudiantes que estudien aprobaran el examen.

Comment: `desde` is more likely to be translated as `from` that `to`. I can't think of a case where it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you mention, "Alegrarse de" it's one of the ways of using the verb. It would be the equivalent of "Being happy about".

As far as I understand, its akin to the phrasal verbs in English.

You wouldn't be happy OF something, but you would be happy about, for, that, etc.

In any case, "de" is one of the most complicated prepositions to learn, as it is used in a loooot of cases. Check the list of uses (as preposition) listed by the Real Academia dictionary:

1. prep. Denota posesión o pertenencia. La casa de mi padre. La paciencia de Job.
2. prep. U. para crear diversas locuciones adverbiales de modo. Almorzó de pie. Le dieron de puñaladas. Se viste de prestado. Lo conozco de vista.
3. prep. Denota de dónde es, viene o sale alguien o algo. La piedra es de Colmenar. Vengo de Aranjuez. No sale de casa.
4. prep. Denota la materia de que está hecho algo. El vaso de plata. El vestido de seda.
5. prep. U. para señalar lo contenido en algo. Un vaso de agua. Un plato de asado.
6. prep. Denota asunto o materia. Este libro trata de la última guerra. Una clase de matemáticas. Hablaban de la boda.
7. prep. Denota la causa u origen de algo. Murió de viruelas. Fiebre del heno.
8. prep. U. para expresar la naturaleza, condición o cualidad de alguien o algo. Hombre de valor. Entrañas de fiera.
9. prep. U. para determinar o fijar con mayor viveza la aplicación de un nombre apelativo. El mes de noviembre. La ciudad de Sevilla.
10. prep. desde (‖ con idea de punto en el espacio o en el tiempo). De Madrid a Toledo. Abierto de nueve a una.
11. prep. U. precedida de sustantivo, adjetivo o adverbio, y seguida de infinitivo. Es hora de caminar. Harto de trabajar. Lejos de pensar.
12. prep. U. seguida de infinitivo con valor condicional. De saberlo antes, habría venido.
13. prep. U. precedida de un verbo para formar perífrasis verbales. Dejó de estudiar. Acaba de llegar.
14. prep. U. con ciertos nombres para determinar el tiempo en que sucede algo. De madrugada. De mañana. De noche. De viejo. De niño.
15. prep. U. para reforzar un calificativo. El bueno de Pedro. El pícaro del mozo. La taimada de la patrona.
16. prep. U. como nota de ilación. De esto se sigue. De aquello se infiere.
17. prep. U. con valor partitivo. Dame un poco de agua.
18. prep. Denota la rápida ejecución de algo. De UN trago se bebió la tisana. De UN salto se puso en la calle. Acabemos de UNA vez.
19. prep. U. entre distintas partes de la oración con expresiones de lástima, queja o amenaza. ¡Pobre de mi hermano! ¡Ay de los vencidos!
20. prep. U. para la creación de locuciones prepositivas a partir de adverbios, nombres, etc. Antes de. Respecto de. Alrededor de. A diferencia de.
21. prep. U. también combinada con otras preposiciones. De a tres. De a bordo. De por sí. Por de pronto. Tras de sí.
22. prep. U. en ciertas construcciones con el agente de la pasiva. Acompañado de sus amigos. Dejado de la mano de Dios. Está abrumado de deudas.
23. prep. U. para introducir el término de la comparación. He comido más de lo debido. Es peor de lo que pensaba. Ahora escribe más de veinte artículos al año.
24. prep. con (‖ con idea de medio, modo o instrumento para hacer algo). Lo hizo de intento.
25. prep. para. Gorro de dormir. Ropa de deporte.
26. prep. por. Lo hice de miedo.
27. prep. ant. a2.

Don't worry TOO much about it, you will be learning the use slowly :) The first THREE definitions given there cover most cases, in case you want to learn those first.